# Fechar uma conexão MySql sem dar commit ou rollback no c# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, transações

Gostaria de saber o que acontece no seguinte cenário:

Em um programa [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) com [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) foi aberta uma `MySqlConnection`, logo depois foi iniciada uma `MySqlTransaction`, foi realizado um `insert` na transação aberta, porem, em vez de dar um `commit` ou `rollback` na transação, a conexão e fechada.

O que aconteceria com a transação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a ligação for desconectada antes de chegar ao `COMMIT`, acontece um `ROLLBACK` automático.

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html):

> With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state.

> After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB or NDB) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.

Basicamente, quando se inicia uma transacção a flag `autocommit` é desligada. Enquanto continuar desligada, as alterações não são persistidas até ser executado um `COMMIT`. Se a ligação cair, as alterações nunca foram persistidas - e, portanto, não fazem efeito.